# How to use simple file input and output in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, input, output

Can someone please tell me how basic file input and output is supposed to be performed in C. I tried searching but I could get only solutions for C++ etc.

I am trying to use fscanf and fprintf to do this. However, the program crashes as soon as it executes this part with the error message saying: "Unhandled exception at 0x50D39686 (msvcr120d.dll) in Test Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC." The file cats.txt is in location Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test Project\Test Project My code is pasted below

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()

{
    double things_in_file[6];
int counter;
FILE *file_cats;

if ((file_cats = fopen("cats.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("This file doesn't exist.\n");
    system("pause");
    exit(-1);
}

for (counter = 0; counter <= 5; counter = counter + 1)
{

    fscanf(file_cats, "%lf\n", &things_in_file[counter]);
    printf("%f\n", things_in_file[counter]);

}

fclose("file_cats");
system("pause");

exit(0);
```

}

---

**I figured out what was wrong. The line `fclose("file_cats")` should be `fclose(file_cats)`. That fixes the issue for me.**

Comment: `counter <= 5` should be `counter < 5` and fscanf ... `&things_in_file[counter]`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - Your comment should be an answer.  And tell the OP that he is overrunning the array buffer.

Comment: The fact that you program in MS VS 2013 is irrelevant for this question. Reading from files is standard and should work regardless of the IDE.

Comment: I just changed the dimension of the array from 5 to 6. But I still get this error message: "Unhandled exception at 0x50F79686 (msvcr120d.dll) in Test Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC."

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed the comment pointning ou the missing "&" in fscanf function. I fixed that too. I do get the values from cat.txt listed in the black window, but I get this message soon after:
"Unhandled exception at 0x50DC7EEB (msvcr120d.dll) in Test Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00EE58D8."

Comment: Sorry about posting so many comments at once. I noticed that this message comes when the program reaches the fclose line. I added the `system("pause")` bit inside the loop and all the values appeared one by one in that black window. However, after the final value, I get this message. There are options to "Break", "Continue" and "Open Exception Settings". So can someone please tell me what's going on here and how can I stop this from happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array declaration eg `array[5]` is 5 element, index from 0 to 4 (0,1,2,3,4)

`scanf` requires the address of the variable to store the value